# How to debug the error "unsupported operand type" in my student grading script?

Tags: python

What did I do wrong in this code? I've been working on this for a school assignment and every time I think I've fixed it, it comes up with this error:

```
 line 63, in averageClaculation
    totalClassScore = totalClassScore + classlist[i][0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Here's my code:

```
ACHIEVED = 50
MERIT = 70
EXCELLENCE = 90
testName = ""
classNameLimit = ""
classLimit = ""
classlist = []
highClasslist = []
lowClasslist = []


def grading(studentScore):
if studentScore < ACHIEVED: #If the mark is between 0 and 50 a Not Achived is given
    studentGrade = "Not Achieved"
elif studentScore >= ACHIEVED and studentScore < MERIT:  #If the mark is between 50 and 70 an Acheived is given
    studentGrade = "Achieved"
elif studentScore >= MERIT and studentScore < EXCELLENCE:  #If the mark is between 70 and 90 a merit is given
    studentGrade = "Merit"
elif studentScore >= EXCELLENCE and studentScore <=100:  #If the mark is between 90 and 100 an Excellence is given
    studentGrade = "Excellence"
return studentGrade

def enteringData():
testName = input("What is the name of the test? ")
name = input("What is your name? ").title()
teacher = input("Who is the teacher that conducted the test? ").title
className = input("What is the class name?: ")
classSize = int(input("How many students are in the class? "))
print()
for i in range(0, classSize):
    newStudent = ()
    studentsName = input("Enter student name {0}: ".format(i+1)).title()
    enterScore = True
    while enterScore == True:
        studentScore = int(input("    Enter the score {0} got for the test: ".format(studentsName)))
        if studentScore < 0 or studentScore > 100:
            print("Enter a number between 0 and 100\n")
            studentScore = int(input("    Enter the score {0} got for the test: ".format(studentsName)))
        else:
            break
    studentGrade = grading(studentScore)
    print("      The grade is " +str(studentGrade))
    classlist.append([newStudent])
    print()

def highestCalculation(classlist):
classlist.sort(reverse = True)
topThree = [classlist[0], classlist[1], classlist[2]]
return topThree

def averageClaculation(classlist):
totalClassScore = 0
for i in range(0, len(classlist)):
    totalClassScore = totalClassScore + classlist[i][0]
average = totalClassScore/len(classlist)

def main():
enteringData()
highestCalculation(classlist)
averageClaculation(classlist)
anotherClass = input("Would you like to enter results for another class? 'y' or 'n' ").upper()
if anotherClass == "Y":
    classList = []
    highClasslist = []
    lowClasslist = []

#Main Routine
main()
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code? Indentation is significant in Python, so it's much harder to troubleshoot code where some of the indentation has been messed up in the process of formatting it for this site.

Comment: Your statement `classlist.append([newStudent])` is appending an empty tuple to `classlist` every time. That is probably not what you intended.

Comment: When asking a question about code, that question should include a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible code** that generates a **specific problem**, described in detail in the question itself; with everything not needed to produce that problem or otherwise unrelated to it removed. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) will likewise do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception message tells you that `classlist[i][0]` is a tuple, rather than the integer that part of your code expects. To figure out why you're getting the wrong type, you need to figure out where the `classlist` variable is defined, and how it's value gets updated.

That occurs in `enteringData`, where you define `newstudent` to be an empty tuple, then later do `classlist.append([newStudent])`. So `classlist` is a list of one-element lists of empty tuples. That's almost certainly not what you want to be doing. Exactly what data you're supposed to be saving is not clear, but probably you want to do something like `classlist.append([student_score])` (with maybe other values included in the list, after the score). You could also put the extra values before  thes core, but then you'd need to update the other functions to check the appropriate indexes. You might also be able to get rid of the inner list entirely, and just have `classlist` as a list of integers (use `classlist.append(student_score)` then, and get rid of the `[0]` index in the average calculation).

Comment: Thank you this worked. I've been told my code is a pass which means I get three credits thank you so much